# Laravel Scheduler: Run every x hours except for given times

Tags: php, laravel

I know we can specify certain tasks for every `X` individual times like following will run after every two hours:

```
$schedule->command('catalog:update')->cron('0 */2 * * *');
```

However, I need to run every two hour but still be able to exclude certain times. For example, Scheduler should run my task every two hours but not between these times: 12 am to 5 am

I was thinking of putting current time check login in task itself which might work. Is there any other better or laravel-specific way of doing it ?

Thanks for the help/suggestions

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Laravel Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling) with `hourly()` and `unlessBetween()`.

> The `unlessBetween` method can be used to exclude the execution of a task for a period of time

An example:

```
->hourly()->unlessBetween('00:00', '5:00');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options

Comment: just a question, will this run at 00:00 and then every hour or at 01:00 and then every hour

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute command except at duration between 12 am to 5 am just think reverse of it. Execute the command only between 5 am to 12 am using `between` keyword.

You can use between which limit the task to run between start and end times like

```
$schedule->command('test')->cron('0 */2 * * *')->between('5:00', '00:00');
```